# Conversion from string "FalseTrue" to type 'Boolean' is not valid -Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net

Here is my VB Net code:

```
Public Class Form1

   Dim hue As Single

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles      Button1.Click
   Dim hueMin As Single = 205
     Dim hueMax As Single = 259

            If (hue > hueMin) & (hue < hueMax) Then

                 bmp.SetPixel(Xcor, Ycor, Color.Black)

             End If
   End Sub

End Class
```

I get in this row:

```
            If (hue > hueMin) & (hue < hueMax) Then
```

this exception:

**{"Conversion from string "FalseTrue" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."}**

Any idea how ca i fix the code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your project properties, or at the top of your code, turn Option Strict On and you will save yourself some headaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the right test should be

```
If (hue > hueMin) AndAlso (hue < hueMax) Then 
                   ^^^^
```

the `&` in VB.Net is the String concatenation operator.